# allowing users to register or login with facebook or gmail how would this issue work

Tags: oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, facebook-oauth

I am just getting into this so I am new but I have a simple question that I can't get my mind around: Let say a user registers and logins into your website using Facebook . All is well but if you then take out the login with Facebook option how would that user be able to log back into your website? Assuming that your website uses email and a special hash password for identification. I really like the easy registration/logins via facebook option but i do not want to create a situation were if I remove that option then the users can't login using my website login form.